# Global Variables in Laravel for Views, Controllers, Models etc

Tags: laravel, global-variables

I know this question has been asked before, but I am struggling to find an answer that fits my needs, or is for the most up to date version of Laravel.

Basically, I have a load of variables that will be created using data from the Route and the database.  For example, I need to use the Route to set a variable called "current_page" which extracts details from the "pages" table using the unique url column. (`$current_page = Page::where('url', <url-taken-from-route>)->first();`)

$current_page will need to contain several relationships. There are also other global variables such as `$current_site` (this is a kind of multi-site environment with one home page and nested microsites) etc.

I feel the configuration files are not the right place to create these variables as a) the value of the variables can be nested and complicated and b) they are not constants but data retrieved from a database.

View Composers obviously only work with views, and a Helper class just feels too generic considering we are dealing with pages, sites, and possibly other global variables.

I gather global variables are frowned upon, but these truly are global. The values will always be the same (albeit dynamic) on every occasion, and will be required by most views and controllers.

I have also thought about putting methods in my already existing `Page` and `Site` controllers so I can call `Page::current()`, but am not sure putting static methods in a mostly non-static controller is the right thing to do. Also, this would make a database call every time I called Page::current() rather than having the current page stored in memory somewhere.

For now, I have created a BaseController which all other controllers extend from. I have put these variables in the constructor and manually passed them to the view in each method. (I know that is messy and doesn't work for models).

So what is the best solution here? Where to declare a global variable that can be used anywhere, but doesn't feel hacky?

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions where to save global variables? Thanks

Comment: Are global variables really this difficult in Laravel?